# What is the best approximation of the function of the graph y = $p_n$ that holds for large n?

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, graphing-functions, approximation

I'm looking into a pattern for the the primes and I want to find an approximate formula or curve of best fit that graphs all prime numbers up to arbitrarily large n. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: I'm not looking for the pi(X) function I'm looking for a graph of the primes.

Comment: Dusart established quite good bounds for the $n$-th prime number. Concerning the pattern : We know much about the distribution of primes , but almost nothing when it comes to concrete primes. Even such an easy statement "There are infinite many primes of the form $n^2+1$" can currently neither be proven nor be disproven. Several structures have been found (like Ulam's spiral) , but they vanish for larger primes.

Comment: With the PNT you can still do something like this: $$p_n\approx n \ln(n)$$

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131683/asymptotic-bounds-on-pi-1x-inverse-prime-counting-function). Also, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number)